# Getting the ID of an HTML Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have these in my aspx page:

```
<input runat="server" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" type="submit" OnServerClick="ibtn_Click"  />
<input runat="server" name="btnCancel" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" type="submit" OnServerClick="ibtn_Click" />
```

And in code behind inside the method "ibtn_Click" I added this line to get the id of a particular button:

```
HtmlGenericControl btn = sender as HtmlGenericControl;
```

But I got an error saying "Use the 'new' keyword to create an object instance."

Comment: what u need to do is HtmlGenericControl btn = new HtmlGenericControl("button");

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just want to clarify the "button" inside the HTMLGenericControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void ibtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        HtmlInputButton input = (HtmlInputButton)sender as HtmlInputButton;
        string ControlID = input.ID.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this.